# about android toolbar, how to hide defualt setting menu in toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

about android `Toolbar`, how to hide default setting menu in toolbar

in the this activity i hava set a single icon menu,like this –

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
       android:title=""
       android:id="@+id/menu_add"
       android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_add_icon"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
</menu>
```

it is menu/main_home.xml

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

but it show a three dots menu. i want know why

[image]

and how to show sub menu icon image ，it is normal in the `Actionbar`, but hide in the `Toolbar`

Comment: Edit your menu xml file related to the particular activity and remove the menu item for this particular item.

Answer (score 6):

1. If you want to empty the contents of the menu, go to the **res/menu** folder and delete the item tags from the **menu_main.xml** file. You will  also need to delete references to the items in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. The menu dots will disappear if there are no items.
2. If you want to completely remove the three dots menu, then go to the `onCreateOptions(...)` method in your code and delete it, or simply remove the `getMenuInflater().inflate(...);` portion of it. You can safely remove the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method as well because it will have no purpose.
3. The simplest way to make the menu disappear is to have the `onCreateOptions(...)` method return **false**.

Comment: yeah,your are right, but in the this activity i hava set a single icon menu,like this –
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:title=""
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_add_icon"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
   

</menu>

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

but it show a three dots menu.  i want  know why~

Answer (score 2):

this question is solved   use app:showAsAction ="ifRoom" not android:showAsAction ="ifRoom"

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:title=""
    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_single_button"
    app:showAsAction = "always"
     /></menu>
```